# Additive continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Prove that if $f$ is additive and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then 
$\forall c,x\in\mathbb{R}, f(cx)=cf(x)$.

> I have proved it for $c\in\mathbb{Q}$, but how to prove it for $c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Let $c\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$. By density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$, there is a sequence $(c_n)$ of $\mathbb Q$ s.t. $c_n\to c$ whenever $n\to \infty $.

Comment: Yes,but after that how to proceed further?

Comment: $f(c_nx)=c_nf(x)$. @Manu

Comment: OK, now I have understood.